# Is it safe to do full disc encryption without ECC DRAM?

Tags: disk-encryption, memory

Our institution requires disc encryption on laptops, but I'm uneasy about using full disc encryption without [SECDED ECC DRAM](http://cr.yp.to/hardware/ecc.html).

Is it safe to use full disc encryption on laptops with unreliable memory?

Answer (score 2):

While the usage of error-correcting memory is a plus in preventing data loss due to sector corruption in the event of memory errors, it is not a requirement for full disk encryption.

Considering that most people do use FDE on computers that do not have error-correcting memory, it should be safe.